# Unable to get object data when used multiple-argument function

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

I am unable to get the data of an object

```js
var a = {
  'ab':'cd',
  'ef':'gh',
  'ij':'kl'
}
function fun(...val){
  console.log(a.val[0])
}
fun('ab','ef')
```

It should output 'cd' but it is giving out error in the console
any idea how do i fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation like so:

```js
var a = {
  'ab':'cd',
  'ef':'gh',
  'ij':'kl'
}
function fun(...val){
  console.log(a[val[0]])
}
fun('ab','ef')
```

Your code was trying to get the property named `val` in `a` (doesn't exist), then get the first character/item of that value (trying to do this to `undefined` causes the error).